# Youtube Javascript API to create audio bar

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

For people that have experience with the Youtube Javascript API, I was wondering would it be possible to create a completely customized audio player using the API. My objective is to simply use the API to play sound from a embed youtube video, pause, change volume, from javascript buttons, without ever displaying the flash object itself. Does the API allow this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Take a look at this: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_example_1.html
You'll see that you can have full range of control.  If you do not want to display the flash object, set the width and height equal to zero.

Comment: Ok I just wanted to make sure that setting height and width to 0 wouldn't affect functionality